# STS vs native Eclipse with Spring IDE plugin

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I've just been given several tasks requiring Spring and so I've been going through tutorials and I came across STS on the Spring.io website which is built atop Eclipse (my favorite IDE).  On the other hand, I mentioned my discovery to several well seasoned Spring developers who switched after they were told at a workshop several years ago. They were told that STS is not stable and I guess they didn't think much SPRING IDE plugin either.

My question: were those observations valid say 3 years ago?  And today, several major releases of Spring later, are they still valid? Does the Spring IDE plugin have the same issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As one of the team members at Pivotal working on STS and the Spring IDE, I might be very biased on this... :-) But what I can tell you is that we worked quite a lot on performance and stability of the Spring IDE and STS implementations - and the underlying Eclipse implementation improved quite a bit again as well. The recent Eclipse platform version 4.4 and the upcoming version 4.5 is a lot better again than the early 4.x versions, especially compared to Eclipse 4.2. The STS specific parts have improved since then as well, so it would be a lot better than a few years ago, I would say.

Not saying that there aren't any bugs or issues in STS anymore. We continue to work on the performance as an ongoing activity - the same for the stability and new features.

I would give STS 3.6.4 a try to see if it fits your needs. And if not, please let us know. If STS doesn't work the way you expect it to work, let us know, and we will work on fixing it.

Comment: Great job. What makes me speechless is that STS seems more stable than e.g. the (currently) latest Eclipse Neon.2 J2EE package.

Everything seems to be snappier and with less problems. You might want to open up a ticket with recommendations on the default eclipse configuration.